# Explicitly define $GL(V)$, $V= \mathbb{C}^2$ with a Hermitian form

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

The problem:

$V = \mathbb{C}^2$, with Hermitian form defined $(x,y)=x_{1} \bar y_{1} + x_{2} \bar y_{2}$. Find explicitly set $\{ g \in GL_{2}(\mathbb{C}) \space \vert \space (gx, gy)=(x,y)\}$.

I don't know where to start. It seems like a problem that has an idea-driven solution, but also since I'm asked to find a structure on this subset of $ GL_{2}(\mathbb{C})$, it feels like I could do it by hand if I spend enough time on distributing everything,
because having $(gx, gy) = (x,y)$ would mean that their Hermitian forms are also equal, and I could try to find out what those would be. But then I have to deal with 8 complex numbers.

Any suggestions on where to start? Thank you

Comment: It's the set of matrices $g$ such that $g{^t\overline g}=I_2$.